# How to bundle up a set of Typescript classes and use it in other angular2/typescript projects?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a set of classes and interfaces.

Folder structure

-Myutilityservice
--classes
---SankeyUtilService.ts

This .ts file has a class

```
export class SankeyUtilService {
// code goes here..
}
```

This project would be pulled in the other through npm/bower.
I want my classes to be available in other projects, through an import statement.

Like this

```
import {SankeyUtilService} from 'Myutilityservice/classes';
```

How to do such a configuration? Please provide some samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expose project as an npm package by following these steps:

1) Create index.ts that will export all required classes:

```
export * from "./lib/Helper";
export * from "./lib/Log";
// ....
export * from "./lib/Query";
```

2) Make shure you transpile ts file with `declarations` flag enabled - so you will get nice d.ts file alongside.

3) In your package.json specify transpiled index.js and index.d.ts like in the example below:

```
"main": "dist/index.js",
"typings": "typings/index.d.ts",
```

4) Publish your transpiled sources with definitions to NPM.

After these steps you will be able to access your package like this:

```
import * as MyLib from 'MyLib';
let h = new MyLib.Helper();
```

As an example - you can check a project [here](https://github.com/magnetnation/mgCore).