# Typescript local dependencies (Multiple Projects)

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I am new in typescript. I am currently trying to create a project structure with dependencies to each other. There are three projects `core`, `calculator` and `tax-calculator`. The project `tax-calculator` needs code from the `calculator` project, which needs the content from the `core` project. The `core` and `calculator` project should be libraries and the `tax-calculator` should be an web interface. The reason why i split the code is, that i need the `core` and `calculator` in other projects too.

```
core
    |--src
        |--MathUtils.ts
        |--...
    |--dist
        |--MathUtils.js

calculator
    |--src
        |--Calculator.ts // needs MathUtils.ts
    |--dist
        |--Calculator.js

tax-calculator
    |--src
        |--TaxCalculator.ts // needs Calculator.ts
    |--dist
        |--TaxCalculator.js
```

How can i provide that the sources are available in the other projects using `npm` or `webpack`? I am using VisualStudio Code, i want to use autocomplition and the other features while developing like when i using the `@types/chrome` or other types.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493029/how-to-bundle-up-a-set-of-typescript-classes-and-use-it-in-other-angular2-typesc/43495206#43495206

Comment: I believe you could use something like yarn workspaces for this? https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/

Answer (score 4):

Little late to the party, but I will provide different options available as of today, December 2018:

#### Custom setup using node/shell scripts like done in Cycle.js:

[Setting up JavaScript Monorepo](https://staltz.com/setting-up-a-javascript-monorepo.html).

#### Using Lerna:

Many big projects including Babel, Marble.js, Material, Angular use Lerna for multi-package setup.

#### Typescript Project References:

TypeScript 3.0 now provides a support for [Project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html).

#### Git submodules

Git submodules can be also used, though it is not just TypeScript. It can be used for sharing any type of code. Ghost blogging platform uses this approach. I would not really recommend this approach unless you know all the issues associated with this.

Also, if you are using Yarn, you can consider workspaces, though I am not sure how well it plays with TypeScript.

Comment: The fact that such a simple use case has no clear answer illustrates how much the JS infrastructure sucks. This would be a no-brainer with Java and Maven.

Comment: @MartynasJusevičius I agree. However, JS has vast universal use-cases in different environments. Deriving a common denominator without introducing backward-compatibility has its own costs.

Comment: BTW `references` in `tsconfig.json` worked for me, but I had to specify `imports { Class } from '../../lib'` using relative paths, which I'm not fond of.
But I guess I can get rid of the paths when I publish the referenced lib as an npm package and specify it in `package.json` as a proper dependency. Would that be the way to go?

Comment: @MartynasJusevičius That is how it would evolve. The problem will happen when you have `src` and `dist` as two separate folders and you are using individual files imports like `@mypackage/dist/file1.js`. The `dist` word keeps appearing.