# Change the plugin [index and package file ] into typescript with JS-plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, plugins, package

I am new to Typescript. I recently heard about JS-Plugins and implemented it with JavaScript format. When I convert the entire thing into Typescript [ plugin's index and package file ] and handle it in the host application seems error. Guys please help me.

**index.d.ts** file [ Plugin side ]

```
declare function hai (data: any, host: any, options: any){
  return {
    hello: function(){
      return "happy scriptring";
  }
 };
}

export = hai;
```

But index.d.ts file shows error " [ts] An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.".
And i placed the both file in a folder under .node_modules

**package.json** file [ Plugin side ]

```
{
 "name": "js-plugins-example-people",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "extensions": {
 "sample:plugin": {
     "john": "./"
    }
  }
}
```

**host.js** file [ Application side ]

```
var hostObj = '';

pluginManager.scanSubdirs([__dirname]);
pluginManager.scan();
pluginManager.connect(hostObj, 'sample:plugin', {multi: true}, 
function (err: any, outputs: any, names: any) {
  outputs.map(function(values: any){
  console.log(values.hello());
})
console.log("Hello World");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `declare` keyword is used when a function (or class or module or variable) is not implemented in Typescript but is implemented in Javascript and we just want to let the compiler know about the function. In such cases you don't declare the body of the function in Typescript (because it is defined in Javascript):

**index.d.ts**

```
declare function hai(data: any, host: any, options: any): {
    hello(): string
}
export = hai;
```

If you want to implement the function in Typescript, then the `declare` keyword should not be used, and the file should have an extension of just `.ts` not `d.ts` (the `d` is for declaration)

**index.ts**

```
function hai(data: any, host: any, options: any) {
    return {
        hello: function () {
            return "happy scriptring";
        }
    };
}

export = hai;
```

Comment: @titian-cerniconva-dragomir   how to specify index.ts visibility to outside world in package.json `{
 "name": "js-plugins-example-people",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "extensions": {
 "sample:plugin": {
     "john": "./"
    }
  }}`

Comment: @JohnDavis this question describes what you should do to export types from a module : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493029/how-to-bundle-up-a-set-of-typescript-classes-and-use-it-in-other-angular2-typesc

Comment: I couldn't get the plugin in my host typescript application

Answer (score 0):

We need to add "typings" package in application side. And add things below in your plugin side.

```
{
"name": "sampleplugin",
"version": "0.0.1",
"typings": [
    "./globals.ts"
],
"extensions": {
    "default": {
        "default": "./globals.ts"
    }
 }
}
```